# Мобильная версия сайта.(input)

Tags: javascript, html, css

Здраствуйте, такая проблема, есть сайт, и на нем есть инпут с placeholder , как сделать так что при изменении екрана под телефон плейсхолдер также менялся?

```
let currentWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth
let pls = document.getElementById("pls")


if (currentWidth < 575) {
  pls = pls.setAttribute("placeholder", "lololo")
}
else {
  pls = pls.setAttribute("placeholder", "laaaaa")
}
```

Comment: менялся в каком смысле? стили? или текст надписи?

Comment: Текст надписи.
Если на декстопной версии надпись пишет например "Здраствуйте"
То на мобильной нужно чтоб надпись менялась на "Здраствуйте все"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проверяете ширину экрана, и если она меньше какого-то условного "мобильного" размера, меняете значение плейсхолдера:

```js
function changePlaceHolder() {
  if($(window).width() < 576) {
    $('input').attr('placeholder', 'Здравствуйте все');
  }
  else {
    $('input').attr('placeholder', 'Здравствуйте');
  }
}

changePlaceHolder();

$(window).resize(function(){
  changePlaceHolder();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" placeholder="Здравствуйте">
```

В принципе можно сделать имитацию плейсхолдера и смену его содержимого на чистом css (без js/jquery), но придётся пошаманить со стилями:

```css
input {
  background: none;
}
input:valid {
  background-color: white;
}
div {
  position: relative;
}
div:focus-within:before {
  display: none;
}
div:before {
  content: attr(data-desktop);
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  top: 1px;
  color: gray;
  z-index: -1;
}
@media (max-width: 575px) {
  div:before {
    content: attr(data-mobile);
  }
}
```

```html
<div data-desktop="Здравствуйте" data-mobile="Здравствуйте все">
<input type="text" required>
</div>
```

Comment: А можно переписать на чистом js?

Comment: @DartVinnie, можно - перепишите ))

Comment: У меня не получанеться в умове написать ширину екрана , как ето сделать?

Comment: нет, уже получилось, можете глянуть правильно ли, щас проблема в тому что в реальном времени не переключаеться, а только когда перезапускаю страницу, я добавил код к своему вопросу, помогите пожалуста.

Comment: @DartVinnie, ну, запихните теперь всё это в window.onresize = function(){ ... } У меня же в ответе написано

Comment: Тупанул очень сильно, спасибо огромное.